# JNI bitmap size exceeds VM budget when calling getXXArrayRegion( )

Tags: android, jvm, java-native-interface

I pass a bitmap's color array to the JNI layer and when I try to call the getIntArrayResion method, I encounter "bitmap size exceeds VM budget" error. Dose anyone have an idea how to deal with this problem?

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_happy_MainActivity_Parsing( JNIEnv* env,
    jintArray bmapColorArray)
{
    int length = env->GetArrayLength(bmapColorArray);
    int * buffer;
    buffer = new int[length];
    env->GetIntArrayRegion(bmapColorArray,0,length, buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, can I directly use the bmapColorArray instead of copy them to a buffer. I don't know why I should copy it, it's really time and space consuming. I did that just follow the Android Development Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your app ran out of memory.  You need to use less.  If you're using a lot of bitmaps, make sure to recycle them when you're done-  the garbage collector can take a very long time to run and clean them up.